# Inheriting sandbox permissions for someone else's process

Tags: java, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I have a sandboxed MacOS X app with an entitlements file. It has a line for  `com.apple.security.smartcard`, and it's required for access to PCSC API. The API works, everything is fine. If I remove the line from the entitlements file, the PCSC API errors out, and the system console displays a corresponding message.

Now I would like to start a subprocess - `/usr/bin/java`. It looks like the subprocess doesn't inherit the entitlement. Trying to access a smartcard fails, and the console displays the same error.

One solution is presented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW15), but it requires changing the entitlements for the subprocess itself. Since `java` is not my executable, I can't.

Is there a way to start **someone else's** subprocess with permission inheritance? I'm using `NSTask` to launch it.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this? We are using `/usr/bin/ssh` to connect to a remote host, using a `NSTask`, but that process can't access a YubiKey. Console.app reports `Refusing sandboxed PCSC.framework client without com.apple.security.smartcard entitlement`

Comment: No. The project went away on its own.

Comment: See if you can run an SSH session *in the same process*. That would work for Java too.